# Select by attribute of parent node in xpath query

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, selenium-webdriver, nodes

I'm scraping a website with the following structure:

```
<tbody>
   <tr class='Leaguestitle'>
      <td>...<\td>
      <td>...<\td>
   <\tr>
   <tr id='tr1_abababa'>
      <td>...<\td>
      <td>...<\td>
   <\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_abababa'>..<\tr>
    .
    .
   <tr id='tr1_acacaca'>..<\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_acacaca'>..<\tr>
   <tr align='center'>..<\tr>
    .
    .
   <tr id='tr1_cbcbcbc'>..<\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_cbcbcbc'>--<\tr>
<\tbody>
```

What I want is loop thorugh all tr with a class, and all tr with tr1 in its id, until I reach the node with align center, when I stop the query. To do so I try with the following xpath:

```
allrows=table.find_elements_by_xpath(
        './/tr[@class="Leaguestitle"] | .//tr[contains(@id,"tr1")] | .//tr[@align="center"]')
```

And my idea to classify each node was something like this:

```
for row in allrows:

   try:
     if 'Leaguestitle' in row.get_attribute('class'): something
   except:pass       

   try:
     if 'tr1' in row.get_attribute('id'): something else
   except:pass

   try:       
     if 'center' in row.get_attribute('align'): break
   except:pass
```

Problem is, the node I get is not of the structure

```
<tr attributes>
  <td>...<\td>
  <td>...<\td>
<\tr>
```

But directly all the child tags. To try and solve it, I did

```
for row in allrows:
   row=row.find_element_by_xpath('..')
```

That, when printing gave me the whole parent tag, but I was still unable to use my classification code, because get_attribute returned empty results.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
allrows = table.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='Leaguestitle' or contains(@id,'tr1') and not (@align='center')]")
```

Comment: That gives me invalid because is not a xpath expression. Besides,wouldn´t that give me all tr tags after the one that is align? In any case, my problem is not choosing the nodes, which I do, but being able to sort them after by tr tag attributes

Comment: It did work. But I think my question was unclear. My problem is not selecting the nodes, is that after doing that, if I loop I can't classify them by those attributes one by one because what I get is all child nodes INSIDE that specific "tr" node, and not the whole "tr" node to classify by class or id attribute